# how to pass table row data from one page to another in php

Tags: php, arrays

i am getting a json data and convert into array and echo inside the table.
I am use session and echo.
now iwant to pass the row data to another page when i try  it is getting the last row data when I click.
 i have a submit buttonin every row when i click on that button it want to pass the row values

my output/echo

[image]

```
<?php
    session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>

        <?php

$baseurl = 'http://202.124.173.189/api/v1/doctorAvailability';    
$rawPOSTdata = array
                (
                    "type" => "private",
                    "hosID" => $_POST['hosMaptxt'],
                    "specID" => $_POST['specialityMaptxt'],
                     "date" => $_POST['date'],
                    "name" => '%'.$_POST['docname'].'%'
                );

$curl = curl_init($baseurl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',"Authorization: Bearer $atoken")); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($rawPOSTdata));    
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

 if( $response )
     {
        if ( isset($result->error) )die( $result->error_message );
        /* Convert json data to array */

        $arr=json_decode( $response, true );

    ?>
<body>
        <form method ="post" action="sessiondetails.php" >

    <h2> Avilable Doctors </h2>             
    <table >
        <tr>
            <th> Doctor</th>
            <th>Specialition</th>
            <th> Hospital </th>
            <th> Town </th>
            <th> Date </th>
            <th> Day </th>
            <th> Booking </th>
            </tr>
<?php
foreach($arr['data']['resultMap'] as $key ) 
//$a=$key['DocName'];
 {

        $_SESSION ['HosCode']=$key['HosCode'] ;
        $_SESSION ['SpecializationId']=$key['SpecializationId'] ;
        $_SESSION ['DoctorNo']=$key['DoctorNo'] ;
        $_SESSION ['AppDay']=$key['AppDay'] ;
        $_SESSION ['AppDate']=$key['AppDate'] ;
        $_SESSION ['DocName']=$key['DocName'] ;
        $_SESSION ['SpecName']=$key['SpecName'] ;
        $_SESSION ['HosName']=$key['HosName'] ;



    //echo"<td>" .$_SESSION ['ID']=$key['DocName'] ."</td>";*/
?> <tr>
        <td><input type="text" readonly="" name ="DoctorNo"value="<?php echo $key['DocName']?>"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" readonly="" name ="SpecializationId"  value="<?php echo $key['SpecName']?> "/></td>
        <td><input type="text" readonly="" name ="HosCode" value="<?php echo $key['HosName']?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" readonly="" name ="HosTown"   style="width:110px "value="<?php echo $key['HosTown']?>"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"  readonly="" name ="AppDate"  style="width:80px "  value="<?php echo $key['AppDate']?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text"  readonly="" name ="AppDay"  style="width:80px " value="<?php echo $key['AppDay']?>" /></td>
         <td ><a href='sessiondetails.php?><font face='sans-serif' size=2 color='black'>More>></a></td>
    </tr>
 <?php 
// echo '<pre>';echo print_r ($arr); echo '</pre>';
 }


 }  


 }}
?> 

    </table>
    </form>

    </head>
```

Comment: so you want the all json data to be passed on the other page?

Comment: create session array and loop in other page

Comment: You can use ajax to get the data

Answer (score 0):

It passes only the last because you have the same name in all the fields. You could use an array:

```
<td><input type="text" readonly="" name ="DoctorNo[]" value="<?php echo $key['DocName']?>"  /></td>
```

So in the next page you will get all names in the `$_POST['DoctorNo']` array.
The same goes for all your inputs.

Since all the rows of inputs are in the same form, all values are posted when you click submit.

Comment: How do you try to access it? Try `print_r($_POST['DoctorNo'])` to see its format.

Comment: it is passing all column data not the selected data

Comment: You either have to put each row of inputs in a different form or use js and put a listener on the button to know which one you pressed and send it along the post